# Persistence to a csv file with live modifications

Tags: .net, csv, persistence

I have two major requirements for persisting my data:

1. Have it stored in a clean and expandable format like CSV.
2. Have modifications in the data by the user be quickly persisted to avoid loss of data on power/fatal failure.

The first requirement rules out most DB's which usually excel in the second.

Any suggestions on how to implement this ?

My data is mostly tabular, so there are no model complexity requirements, and the expected size is within tens/hundreds of thousands of records.

The platform is .Net.

Comment: CSV is not a good solution for persisting anything, particularly with live modifications. It's a data transfer format.

Comment: Also note, that if done "right", there is more to CSV than meets (the casual) eye: whitespace, quotes, embedded quotes, in-field-linebreaks, number- and date-formats, etc. A decent and robust CSV writer/reader is more than `StringBuilder.Append()` and/or `String.Split()`. EDIT: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply that you don't know that, but just in case...

Comment: Thanks for mentionong it. I've gained some expiperience parsing csv's under worst conditions (unicode, lazy loading, fields containing stack traces, etc.). I find LumenWorks csvreader does this best of all and fast.

Answer (score 0):

Why not store it in database but not one column = one value but one row = one value?
Sth like this:

```
csvId | value | name?|
    1 | "aaa" | 
    1 | "bbb" |
```

then it's 'expandable'

Comment: It's a viable option I haven't considered.
For simplicity's sake, I want to avoid databases that depend on a 3rd Party library to manipulate or which are not easily portable (no SqlServer, no custom serialization solutions like db4Objects etc).
csv/xml formats for example can be manipulated and ported to other platforms easily.
Csv has the advantage of being more compact and is faster to parse.

Comment: What do you think of this: load all entries on start. On every iser change append the entire record to a running 'log'. When idle and/or when closing consolidate the data file and the log file. The benefits are fast load (especially if loading only n entries at first) fast persistance of changes and a plain csv format. The cons is the heavy consolidation price.